# How to sum the product of multiple elements in XSLT?

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

Please note that I am new to XSLT and will probably never have to use it again.

I have a simplified XML document that looks like the following:

```
<row>
    <tax_allocation_details>
        <tax_allocation_detail>
            <allocation_percent>0.0269</allocation_percent>
        </tax_allocation_detail>
        <tax_allocation_detail>
            <allocation_percent>0.0583</allocation_percent>
        </tax_allocation_detail>
        <tax_allocation_detail>
            <allocation_percent>0.1704</allocation_percent>
        </tax_allocation_detail>
        <tax_allocation_detail>
            <allocation_percent>0.7444</allocation_percent>
        </tax_allocation_detail>
    </tax_allocation_details>
    <ParticipantID>364787525</ParticipantID>
    <TransactionAmount>407252.34</TransactionAmount>
</row>
```

What I'm trying to do is output the sum of all the products of allocation_percent *  TransactionAmount and don't have the slightest idea of how to do that. I'm using XSLT 2.0 and have done some research and found that

```
sum(for $x in node-set return f($x))
```

could be used but I have absolutely no idea how to implement it and don't have the time needed to understand it.

Comment: From what I see, the sum of `allocation_ percent` values is 1 - therefore *"the sum of all the products of allocation_percent * TransactionAmount"* is equal to  `TransactionAmount`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use this XPath 2.0 expression**:

```
sum(/*/*/tax_allocation_detail/allocation_percent/(../../../TransactionAmount * .))
```

**XSLT 2.0 - based verification**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:sequence select=
   "sum(/*/*/tax_allocation_detail/allocation_percent/(../../../TransactionAmount * .))"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<row>
    <tax_allocation_details>
        <tax_allocation_detail>
            <allocation_percent>0.0269</allocation_percent>
        </tax_allocation_detail>
        <tax_allocation_detail>
            <allocation_percent>0.0583</allocation_percent>
        </tax_allocation_detail>
        <tax_allocation_detail>
            <allocation_percent>0.1704</allocation_percent>
        </tax_allocation_detail>
        <tax_allocation_detail>
            <allocation_percent>0.7444</allocation_percent>
        </tax_allocation_detail>
    </tax_allocation_details>
    <ParticipantID>364787525</ParticipantID>
    <TransactionAmount>407252.34</TransactionAmount>
</row>
```

the above XPath expression is evaluated and the result of this evaluation is output:

```
407252.34
```

Comment: This is perfect Dimitre. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

You set up a template that will match tax_allocation_details then sum across the nodes:

```
<xsl:template match="tax_allocation_details">
    <p><xsl:value-of select="sum($tranAmount * tax_allocation_detail/allocation_percent)" /></p>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: You can't multiply a number with a sequence of values, you need to use `sum(tax_allocation_detail/allocation_percent!(. * $tranAmount))` (XPath 3) or `sum(for $p in tax_allocation_detail/allocation_percent return $tranAmount * $p)`.